# Parallel extension of a vector $z\in T_p M$ along coordinate lines

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Here is something Professor Lee did in his book on Riemannian manifolds:

> [image]Given a Riemannian $2$-manifold of $M$, here is one way to attempt to construct a parallel extension of a vector $z\in T_p M$: working in any smooth local coordinates $(x^1,x^2)$ centered at $p$, first parallel transport $z$ along the $x^1$-axis, and then parallel transport the resulting vectors along the coordinate lines parallel to the $x^2$-axis (Fig. 7.1). The result is a vector field $Z$ that, by construction, is parallel along every $x^2$-coordinate line and along the $x^1$-axis. The question is whether this vector field is parallel along $x^1$-coordinate lines other than the $x^1$-axis, or in other words, whether $\nabla_{\partial_1}Z\equiv 0$. Observe that $\nabla_{\partial_1}Z$ vanishes when $x^2=0$. If we could show that
> $$\nabla_{\partial_2}\nabla_{\partial_1}Z=0,\tag{7.1}$$
> then it would follow that $\nabla_{\partial_1}Z\equiv 0$, because the zero vector field is the unique parallel transport of zero along the $x^2$-curves. If we knew that
> $$\nabla_{\partial_2}\nabla_{\partial_1}Z=\nabla_{\partial_1}\nabla_{\partial_2}Z,\tag{7.2}$$
> then (7.1) would follow immediately, because $\nabla_{\partial_2} Z=0$ everywhere by construction.

I'm not certain about the terminology he used here, such as parallel extensions, the $x^1$-axis, coordinate lines, and this is where my question came about. In an earlier chapter, Lee said that a smooth vector field on $M$ is called parallel if it is parallel along every smooth curve in $M$. So I assume that Lee is trying to extend a vector $z\in T_p M$ to a parallel vector field on a neighborhood of $p$. Then I think a little bit about what tools I've got up to now. And it occurs to me that I can first consider the parallel transport of $z$ along the curve
$$t\in x^1(U)\mapsto\phi^{-1}(t,0)\in M,$$
where the pair $(U,\phi)$ denotes the local coordinates $(x^1,x^2)$ centered at $p$ that is picked by Lee. I guess that the curve just defined might be what Lee calls the $x^1$-axis. For more information about coordinate curves/lines, one can consult [Coordinate system - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_system#Coordinate_lines/curves_and_planes/surfaces). Alright, I've got a parallel vector field along a curve. What's next? I don't know what Lee means when he says, "... and then parallel transport the resulting vector***s*** along the ***coordinate lines*** parallel to the $x^2$-axis ...". Is there anyone who looks deeply into the context and would like to share with me? Thank you.

Comment: By working in the coordinate patch $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)^2$, we can drop the $\phi$ for brevity.  So after you get extension of $z$ to the entire $x^1$-axis, you consider parallel transport along every $\gamma_{x^1}\colon t\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\mapsto(x^1,t)$ ("the coordinate lines parallel to $x^2$-axis") and collecting them together as a vector field $Z$.  Now by construction, $\nabla_2 Z=0$ at every $(x^1,x^2)$, so it remains to see if $\nabla_1 Z=0$ at general $(x^1,x^2)$.

Comment: Do you know what is a coordinate? if so coordinate lines aren't clear?

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you. Perhaps I have misunderstood Lee's intentions. He is not planning to construct a parallel vector field on a neighborhood $U$ of $p$, a vector field on $U$ that is parallel along every curve in $U$. What Lee is trying to do is extend a vector to a vector field that is parallel along some special curves, which he calls coordinate lines/curves. Now I can move forward to consider why $\nabla_{\partial_1}Z\equiv 0$.

Comment: @user10354138 Something might be wrong with the statement "$\nabla_2 Z=0$ at every $(x^1,x^2)$." $Z$ could be only parallel along each $x^2$-coordinate line and along the $x^1$-axis. And what's going on next is to determine whether $Z$ is parallel along the other $x^1$-coordinate lines in addition to the one lying on the $x^1$-axis.

Comment: @Steve By construction, $Z$ is parallel along lines $t\mapsto(x^1,t)$ so $\nabla_2Z=0$.  But you don't know whether $Z$ is parallel along the lines $t\mapsto(t,x_2)$ for nonzero $x_2$ (indeed it won't be unless the connection $\nabla$ is flat).

Comment: @user10354138 The way you say $\nabla_2 Z=0$ makes me feel that $\nabla_2 Z$ is vanishing everywhere on the chart. Wait. Are you really insisting on this!?

Comment: @Steve Yes.  That is what parallel transport along lines parallel to $x^2$-axis does --- solving the ODE $\nabla_2 Z=0$ along the integral curves of $\partial_2$.

Comment: @user10354138 Sorry to bother you. Are you saying YES to confirm that $\nabla_2 Z$ vanishes on the chart?

Comment: Yes, $\nabla_2Z$ vanishes by construction.

Comment: @user10354138 Let me open the definition of $\nabla_2 Z$. Fix some suitable number $a$. I think Lee is expressing that $(\nabla_2 Z)_{\phi^{-1}(a,t)}$ vanishes for appropriate $t$'s.

Comment: @user10354138 That's crazy. So I'm totally on the wrong track? Let me digest what you just claimed.

Comment: @user10354138 That $\nabla_2 Z=0$ on the chart seems to be thinkable if we vary $a$ and $t$ in $(\nabla_2 Z)_{\phi^{-1}\ (a,t)}$.

Answer (score 2):

Some technical terms that confused me before are explained in the original post and some comments. Thank those commentators for their kindly help. Now I would like to deduce $\nabla_{\partial_1} Z\equiv 0$ from (7.1) and thus close the question. I hope this would help people who have a hard time understanding Lee's reasoning. To begin with, keep in mind that every zero vector field along an $x^2$-coordinate curve is parallel along the curve. On the other hand, if $\nabla_{\partial_2}(\nabla_{\partial_1}Z)\equiv 0$, then $\nabla_{\partial_1}Z$ is parallel along every $x^2$-coordinate curve. By the uniqueness of parallel transports, we see $\nabla_{\partial_1}Z\equiv 0$.